# WPF OnMouseEnter change image using events

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to access a specific resource in the xaml using events?

I'm trying to have the image change when mouse enters a grid, but the problem is I don't have access to change the image from the event.

I want to do something like:

```
OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
((Image)GetResource("logo")).Source = "pathToImage.jpg";
}
```

Where 'logo' is the name of the image resource.

Comment: "I don't have access to change the image from the event" what does that mean? Doesn't your code compile, or do you get a runtime error? Besides that, there should usually be no need to declare a UI element as resource. So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to change the image source of an image element on my form using an event. When the mouseEnter event fires on a particular element, I would like to be able to change the image of a different element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're just trying to set the Source property of an Image element declared somewhere in your XAML. All you need to do is to set the `x:Name` attribute, which will generate a member in your Window class, like

```
<Image x:Name="image"/>
```

Now you directly access the element in code behind, and assign a value to its Source property like this:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pathToImage.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element you are attaching the `OnMouseEnter` on is a `FrameworkElement` then you can try do something like the following:

```
OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    var image = element.FindResource("logo") as Image;
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pathToImage.jpg"));
}
```

Otherwise you may have to change your "resource" from:

```
<Image x:Key="logo" Source="initialImage.jpg" />
```

to something like:

```
<Image x:Key="logo" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static LogoImage.SingletonInstance}, Path=Logo}" />
```

And have a class something along the lines of:

```
public class LogoImage : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public static LogoImage SingletonInstance { get; } = new LogoImage();

    public ImageSource Logo { get; private set; }
    public void SetLogo(ImageSource image)
    {
        Logo = image;
        RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Logo));
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

}
```

Comment: Hmm, can't get xaml file to compile. :(

Comment: Instead of implementing a singleton, you may directly bind to a static property, including change notification. See here: http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties

Comment: var image = element.FindResource("logo") as Image; is causing exception: System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException: "logo" resource not found